# How to get last record / max value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have PWD which should go like 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004

[image]

So when i want to add the new record in database i get the max value like this

```
sql.Query(" SELECT pwrd FROM users WHERE pwrd = (SELECT max(pwrd ) FROM users)")
        Dim highest As Integer = (sql.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
```

On this way i get the highest row from table example "0004"
Now when adding the new query i need to increment that value for 1 to be "0005"

If i go `TextBox1.Text = Highest + 1` i will get 5 only without "000"

Comment: I'd either use an auto increment column type, or set this value during an insert trigger. Trying to do it in code like this is going to lead to race conditions.

Comment: What do you mean under insert trigger to do autoincrement. How would that query go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add ZEROFILL attribute to the field.

You can create your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY pwd INT(3) zerofill AUTO_INCREMENT not null;
```

**EDIT:**

You can try to drop your table and create like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
   , pwd  AS RIGHT('000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
  )
```

Comment: Just googled it, Probably something like that but how to do it

Comment: @AnelHodzic:- I would suggest to alter your table and then simply insert the pwd normally. To alter the table you can use this sql: `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY pwd INT(3) zerofill AUTO_INCREMENT not null;`

Comment: The problem is this is school assignment and i have primary key autoincrement which is ID  it looks like this. "http://pokit.org/get/img/a63e74fe27d4720d2afcf9d41e74a320.jpg" is it posible to set this autoincrement aswell ?

Comment: @AnelHodzic:- The link you provided is broken. Anyways I have added the alter table script. You just need to run that script and its all done.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, but i made mistake its about MS SQL and this is what i got http://pokit.org/get/?120a1aef7e07c64b1e649b62e9ff1a35.jpg 
Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

Comment: @AnelHodzic:- You added the MySql tag so the answer is for My Sql

Comment: @AnelHodzic:- Updated the answer. Please check now!

Comment: `Msg 2705, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'pwd' in table 'Users' is specified more than once.`. If i try to add new column i got this error   `Msg 1759, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Computed column 'pwd2' in table 'Users' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.`

Comment: @AnelHodzic:- I have updated the query. Please try the latest query. It has alter column not add column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75543/discussion-between-anel-hodzic-and-rahul-tripathi).

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox1.Text = (Highest + 1).ToString.PadLeft("0",4)
```

Not tested so syntax may be off a bit.